# What is the color legend in Android Studio kotlin code?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, legend, color-scheme

I'm learning kotlin currently and trying to understand the studio capabilities.
I see that some of my code is in different color. While I did manage to figure out most of the color legend, Yellow and white are still a mistory to me:

- Orange = Kotlin reserved words
- Purple = member
- Gray = not in use
- Blue = input parameter name
- Green = string
- Yellow? (functions? some cases are still white)
- White? (default?)

  [part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTEXD.png)
  [part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKRPi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the color scheme of the IDE by opening the Settings and navigating to Editor > Color Scheme > Kotlin:

[image: editor color settings]

Here you can even click on parts of the code and it'll show you the relevant color setting.